# How to provide answers to Powershell installation questions?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, windows-installer

I have a `setup.exe` file to install on `Windows Server 2012`. Upon clicking the SETUP file, a `PowerShell` console will popup and will start the installation process. As the process goes through, I will be asked many questions for initial configuration, such as:

```
>username: 
>password:
...................#starts with setup again with verbose outputs
>SQL Server Address: 
>SQL Server Database Name:
..................#starts with setup again with verbose outputs
>Database Username:
>Database user password:
.................#starts with setup again with verbose outputs
>Application Name:
.................#starts with setup again with verbose outputs
..............................................................
```

I install this application from time to time and I want to know if I can write a PowerShell script to give the answers via the script, since I am a newcomer to Powershell, I am here to seek help.

Thanks

Comment: This depends on the software you are actually installing. Ask its provider if there is unattended install mode available. Most installation systems support such measures.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file